# ./adb uinstall Failure after install successfully

Tags: android

I coud do a ./adb install -r myapp.apk

Success

then I immediately do a ./db unistall myapp.apk

then  it listed Failure. NO other message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do `adb uninstall com.yourapp.packagename`, not the apk name